# Application process stays loaded after exit

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, class-library

We have an application that allows custom UI and interaction via SDK.
A DLL is developed for this purpose using VB.Net and the SDK.
An object variable refers to the application and there are some other object variables for components within the application.

Application allows assigning VBScript code to button(s) displayed in toolbar. The VBScript code is:

```
Dim Utility_Main
Set Utility_Main = CreateObject("Utility.Application")
Utility_Main.Launch()
```

This launches a form (custom UI) and users can interact with the application via this form.
Although application itself has its own UI, this utility form is created for database lookup, preserving certain attributes of application objects etc.

In just about every exit point of the form, a procedure is called to unset object variables for application and its components using following code:

========================================

```
    Try
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objX)
    Catch
    End Try

    Try
        objX = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
    Catch
    End Try
```

Note1: ReleaseComObject and setting object variable to Nothing was wrapped in "If (Not objX is Nothing) Then". But it was changed to above format to make sure it gets called.

Note2: GC.Collect was added later to force GC.

========================================

This is done for each object in reverse order of object hierarchy.

Application's executable (Application.exe) remains loaded in both of the following cases:

1. Application is closed first and then Utility form is closed
2. Utility form is closed first and then the application is closed

The only time "Application.exe" goes away is if Application is closed first and then Utility form is closed by clicking on "End Task" in Task Manager.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you say that it was split up for some reason, but this should be:

```
Try    
    If objX IsNot Nothing Then    
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objX)    
    End If    
Catch e As ArgumentException
    ' hopefully you have some debug output here    
Finally    
    objX = Nothing
    GC.Collect() ' really doubt this is necessary
End Try
```

This guarantees that objX is released if it is not `Nothing`, and if that [throws an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) (note the list of exceptions), then you can catch it and figure out what happened. Whether or not an exception is thrown, objX will be set to `Nothing` and the GC will be invoked.

It's probably not this code that is causing your program to stay open. You will need to show more code (how they interact, or any non-daemon threads that you may manually start will also be to blame). It sounds like Utility is forcing the Application to stay alive with a non-daemon, background thread, but it really could be the other way around, and it could be the case that doing that in both directions.

Comment: Thank you pickypg. Your mention of "other way around" made me remove "WithEvents" in declaration of the object variable for the application. Now I can't detect that the application is closed but "Application.exe" is going away regardless of order of closing Application's Main Window and Utility Form Window.

Comment: Glad it helped. You should go through the code that is marked with `Handles` (handled?) for the object's events. I wouldn't be surprised if one of the calls either had an infinite loop, or threw an unhandled exception.

Comment: By the way, I know the syntax is `Handles`, but I wanted to ensure that the phrasing was clear.